# Django | Al tratar de conseguir el username en VIEW devuelve error "name 'request' is not defined"

Tags: python, django

Al tratar de conseguir el valor de username devuelve un error "name 'request' is not defined". Si el request no puedo utilizar de esta manera, ¿Cómo debería conseguir el username en la view?
Gracias.

**Error:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**View.py:**

```
    from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
    class testFilterByModalityAndByUserView(ListView):
        model = TestQuestion
        template_name = 'test/question.html'
    
        def get_queryset(self):
            if request.user.is_authenticated():
                username = request.user.id
                print(username)
```

Comment: Mmm. Estás trabajando dentro de una clase, en teoría todo está bajo la misma clase por así decirlo. ¿Has intentado con `self.request`?

Comment: Gracias una vez más Adrián. Al añadir "self" antes de los request, devuelve: 'bool' object is not callable ¿Por qué puede ser? Gracias.

Comment: Parece que quitando () a authenticated, no devuelve el error "bool". Un saludo.

Comment: ¿Lo has solucionado?

Comment: Sí gracias, eres muy amable Adrián!

Comment: Genial, ¡me alegro haber sido de ayuda!

Comment: Eres un crack! Adrián, admirable. Yo poco a poco cogiendo soltura, me falta mucho todavía. Estoy lucando con un filter con exclude a ver si lo consigo xD. Un saludo y gracias.

Comment: No te creas, llevo poco tiempo con Python. En mi trabajo estoy con Perl y otras tecnologías así que trato de coger solutar con Python por mi cuenta. Un saludo. Ya nos vas comentando que tal todo (para no hacer los comentarios más largos xD).